# If $f,f_m$ are Lipschitz with $\lim_{m\to+\infty} d(f_m(x),f(x)) = 0 $, is it true that the fixed point of $f_m$ converges to the fixed point of $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions, fixed-points

I'm going through a proof in which at one point, the authors make the following statement :

> Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space and $f:X\to X$ and $f_m:X\to X$ Lipschitz with $lip(f)<1$ and $lip(f_m)<1\; \forall m\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $x^*_m$ the fixed point of $f_m$ and $x^*$ the fixed point of $f$.
> If for each  $x\in X$ we have that
> $$\lim_{m\to+\infty} d(f_m(x),f(x)) = 0, $$ it follows that $$\lim_{m\to+\infty} d(x^*_m,x^*) = 0 .$$

I tried to figure out how they came up with this by an argument along the lines of
\begin{align*}d(x^*_m,x^*) &= d(f_m(x^*_m),f(x^*)) \leq d(f_m(x^*_m),f(x_m^*))+ d(f(x_m^*),f(x^*))\\&\leq d(f_m(x^*_m),f(x_m^*))+lip(f)d(x_m^*,x^*).
\end{align*}

Then
$$0\leq (1-lip(f))d(f(x_m^*),f(x^*))\leq d(f_m(x^*_m),f(x_m^*)).$$
But now we can't apply the first limit because $x_m^*$  depends on $m$.

Also another thing I tried is by using the fact that $$\lim_{n
\to+\infty}d(f^{\circ n}(x),x^*)=0 \; \forall x\in X$$
Where $f^{\circ n} = \underbrace{f\circ f\circ \dots \circ f}_{\text {n times}}.$

Then for a fixed $x\in X$
\begin{equation*}d(x^*_m,x^*)\leq d(x^*_m,f^{\circ n}_m(x)) + d(f^{\circ n}_m(x),f^{\circ n}(x))+ d(f^{\circ n}(x),x^*),\; \forall n\in\mathbb{N}
\end{equation*}

Now let $\varepsilon > 0$ and set $N$ big enough so that $d(f^{\circ N}(x),x^*)<\varepsilon/3$ and $d(f_m^{\circ N}(x),x_m^*)< \varepsilon/3$.

Then \begin{align*}
d(x^*_m,x^*) &\leq d(x^*_m,f^{\circ N}_m(x)) + d(f^{\circ N}_m(x),f^{\circ N}(x))+ d(f^{\circ N}(x),x^*)\\&<2\varepsilon/3 + d(f^{\circ N}_m(x),f^{\circ N}(x)).
\end{align*}

Now it can be shown that $\lim\limits_{m\to+\infty} d(f^{\circ N}_m(x),f^{\circ N}(x)) =0$, so there is some $M$ such that $d(f^{\circ N}_m(x),f^{\circ N}(x)) <\varepsilon/3\; \forall m>M$, from which we get $$d(x^*_m,x^*)<\varepsilon.$$

But I feel like something is not right in my second attempt.

Is something missing from the statement?

Comment: I think you need completeness of $(X,d)$ for the iteration process with the $f^{\circ n}$ to work.

Comment: $(X,d)$ is complete, my bad.

Comment: There is a gap in your proof:

Now let $\varepsilon>0$ and set $N$ big enough ... and $d(f_{m}^{oN}(x),x_{m}^{\ast})<\varepsilon/3$.

The problem is that $N$ may depend on $m$.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan Totally agree.

Comment: Would a diagonal argument be helpful to extract the “correct” sequence of functions?

Comment: Are we sure that the proposition is true? I would like to know whether that proposition is known to be true (but just missing a proof) or just a conjecture. If it is a conjecture, I may try to construct counter-examples.

Comment: On the other hand, if there exists $c\in(0,1)$ such that $lip(f_n)\leq c$ for each $n$, the proposition is true and the proof is easy.

Comment: @Son Gohan It is just given that $(X,d)$ is complete but not compact. It is not possible to invoke theorems like Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: So far, every paper I've found requires either $X$ is  locally compact or their must exist a constant $c<1$ such that $\text{lip}_n<c$ for all $n$.

Comment: Also, every paper distinguishes two cases : One is when we have uniform convergence of $f_n$, the other is the pointwise convergence (like Op's statement)

Comment: That is exactly what I suspected. Written as it is, the statement need some kind of additional assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there exists $c\in(0,1)$ such that $lip(f_{n})\leq c$ for all $n$, then it is easy. For, observe that
\begin{eqnarray*}
d(x_{n}^{\ast},x^{\ast}) & = & d(f_{n}(x_{n}^{\ast}),f(x^{\ast}))\\
 & \leq & d(f_{n}(x_{n}^{\ast}),f_{n}(x^{\ast}))+d(f_{n}(x^{\ast}),f(x^{\ast}))\\
 & \leq & lip(f_{n})d(x_{n}^{\ast},x^{\ast})+d(f_{n}(x^{\ast}),f(x^{\ast}))\\
 & \leq & c\cdot d(x_{n}^{\ast},x^{\ast})+d(f_{n}(x^{\ast}),f(x^{\ast}))
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore, $d(x_{n}^{\ast},x^{\ast})\leq\frac{1}{1-c}\cdot d(f_{n}(x^{\ast}),f(x^{\ast})).$
Letting $n\rightarrow\infty$ and observe that $d(f_{n}(x^{\ast}),f(x^{\ast}))\rightarrow0,$
the result follows.

Comment: This might have been what the authors omitted, it seems that it is implied 
throughout the proof, but isn't ever stated. Makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: So basically what is hidden is that the Lipschitz functions $f_m$ need to have all the same Lipschitz constant (below 1, obviously) to get the desired iteration argument, right?

Answer (score 3):

Your theorem is wrong. Next time, I would like you to check your statement carefully to save time of other MSE fellows who want to help you. You know, it is not always easy to tell whether a theorem is true or not.

---

**Counter example**:
Choose $X= l^1(\mathbb{N})$, for all $a \in l^1$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}_*$, $f(a)=0$ and $$f_m(a)=(0,\dots,\underbrace{\frac{1}{m}+(1-\frac{1}{m})a_m}_{m-\text{th position}}, \dots )$$
where $a=(a_0,a_1,\dots,...)$.
So firstly, you can see that $X$ is complete with its canonical norm.
Secondly, $f_m$ converges pointwise to $f$ ( note that $X$ is $l^1$)
And thirdly, the fixed points of $f_m$ are $e_m$, which doesn't converge to $0$- the only fixed point of $f$.

Comment: Nice counterexample!!

Answer (score 1):

I have a strong feeling that one needs uniform convergence and not only pointwise convergence to conclude this. Let me give you a partial answer (I'll think about a counterexample) when we assume $$\lim_{m\to\infty} \sup_{x \in X} d(f_m(x),f(x)) = 0 $$

Indeed note that under this assumption we can write:

$$d(x^*_m,x^*) = d(f_m(x^*_m),f(x^*)) \leq \sup_{y \in X} d(f_m(y),f(y)) \xrightarrow{m \rightarrow \infty} 0$$

In your last attemp you cannot say "set $N$ big enough so that $d(f_m^{\circ N}(x),x_m^*)< \varepsilon/3$" since to write this passage you need uniform convergence (as in the comment is kindly pointed out - I slipped on the dependence of $N$ on $m$, as written in the comment below that does not allow to pass to the limit).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the $=$ was a typo.  I understand now how to salvage my first attempt. In the second one I felt that choosing $N$ might somehow have an effect on $M$ , but I think I got it now.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Are you sure that the second approach is true? Indeed, his $N$ depends on $m$, that's why the limit $\lim\limits_{m\to+\infty} d(f^{\circ N}_m(x),f^{\circ N}(x)) =0$ does not hold.

Comment: I see, the point of “m” fixed is correct, but then we cannot pass to the limit... I suspected something like this, that’s why I wanted to add the uniform convergence that for sure guarantees the theorem.... my bad, I’ll rollback to my previous (partial) answer then... thanks!